# How to add textbox(0) in visual basic 2012

Tags: arrays, vb.net, textbox

On Visual Basic 6.0 you add a TextBox on form and it has a name `TextBox1` after that I copy/paste that TextBox on form and I got `TextBox1(0)`  paste again `TextBox1(1)`
How to do that on Visual Basic 2012 ???
I copy/paste text box and got `Textbox1`  `Textbox2`?
Do you understand the question?

**I tried to copy paste `TextBox1` and I got `TextBox2`**

The code I want to use is to check the TextBoxes
something like

```
Dim i as integer
For i=1 to 5
   textbox(i).text="Anel"
Next
```

Comment: You cannot do it in VB .NET.

Comment: So what is the best posible solution i can do ? You have any idea

Comment: Unfortunately some of us do. Can't be done in .net, you could of course instantiate an array of controls programatically, but that design time option left the building.

Comment: Yes, you can add your textboxes into an ArrayList/Collection and you can access with the `for` loop you mentioned

Comment: `code` For i = 0 To 5
            Dim textbox As New TextBox
            textbox.Name = "Textbox(" & i & ")"
            Me.Controls.Add(textbox)
        Next `code`
@TunZarniKyaw you mean something like this ?
@ Tun Zarni Kyaw

Comment: do you want to create the textboxes dynamically/programmatically? or just want to draw on the form in design time?

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw I want to draw 5 textboxes on a form and set for loop to write 5 letters "A" whenever i load that form something like i allready said

Dim i as integer
For i=1 to 5
   textbox(i).text="Anel"
Next

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to draw FIVE textboxes and ONE button on the form

(1) Declare a `Collection` at class level,

(2) In `Form_Load` event, add your textboxes to the `Collection`

(3) You can access all your textboxes with `for` loop as shown in following code

```
Dim AL As New Collection

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AL.Add(TextBox1)
    AL.Add(TextBox2)
    AL.Add(TextBox3)
    AL.Add(TextBox4)
    AL.Add(TextBox5)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To AL.Count
        AL(i).Text = "Hello"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: that is the thing i wanted to know .. Thanks a lot for your help @TunZamiKyaw  .. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

First create a list of the number of textboxes you want to modify and name the textboxes in a good way 
--> Exemple : 
-----> I have  three textboxes names as following : " ttttaksa1" , "asiuhi2" , "EEFUGUYug3"
-----> We have put a number at the end of the textbox so we can call mofidy each one 
according to its number
-----> Now that we have 3 textboxes , we will make a list of strings with the numbers of our textboxes : in this case : 3 numbers ( NB : The list is of STRINGS ! )
The list will be like that : Dim n as New List(of string)=({"1","2","3"})
if we have 11 textboxes for exemple it will be like that :

> Dim n as New List(of string)=({"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"})

Now , if you want to , for exemple , change the text of the two first textboxes (ttttaska1 and asiuhi2 ) , you will need to do that :

```
For Each textbox In Me.Controls

        For Each s As String In n

            If textbox.Name.ToString.EndsWith(n) Then
                'Do what you want to your textbox ex : textbox.text="Anel"
                 textbox.forecolor=Color.Blue
            End If

        Next
    Next
```

I hope that was useful and thank you :D
I am now making games and selling them , wanna join me ? facebook : Waterfull Idr
Good luck :D

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim textBoxTemp As TextBox
Dim stringData As String

For index = 0 To 23
    stringData = ("txtBoxReal" & index)
    textBoxTemp = CType(Me.Controls(stringData), TextBox)
    textBoxTemp.Text = 0
Next
```